# initialization issue and use of instances in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ZeroClipboard plugin and in the beginning I use this code

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {
            //reset others
            $('.submit').text('Copy');
            ZeroClipboard.config({
                moviePath: clipper_params.templateurl +
                    '/includes/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf'
            });
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard($(this));
            clip.on('complete', function(client, args) {
                $(this).text('Copied');
            });
```

It work but I have to click twice. So I guess it was the initialization issue, I move the instance initialization into document ready like below. But now it seem can't be call. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ZeroClipboard.config({
        moviePath: clipper_params.templateurl +
            '/includes/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf'
    });
    clip = new ZeroClipboard($('.submit'));
});
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {
    //reset others
    $('.submit').text('Copy');
    clip.on('complete', function(client, args) {
        $(this).text('Copied');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know a way to fix it, but you can go round it by simulating the second click on the first click using `trigger()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $('.submit').text('Copy');
    clip.on('complete', function(client, args) {
        $(this).text('Copied');
    });
});
```